# Angularjs: Check / Uncheck checkboxes of categories and list items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, checkboxlist

I've list of categories and list items which i want to have check/uncheck feature. Where clicking on category should also check all child checkboxes. I have a list (of privileges in JSON) where some items have same category like below;

I have example code in plunkr - https://next.plnkr.co/edit/au1XPEjj7MuP77gc

**I've JSON code like below.**

```
var list = [{
      "uuid": "0023",
      "title": "AM_FULL_ACCESS",
      "displayName": "Application monitoring Full access",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "ADMIN",
      "category": "Application Monitoring"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "0025",
      "title": "CM_FULL_ACCESS",
      "displayName": "Client management Full access",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "ADMIN",
      "category": "Client Management"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "0031",
      "title": "COMPLIANCE_FULL_ACCESS",
      "displayName": "Compliance Full access",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "ADMIN",
      "category": "Compliance"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "0054",
      "title": "FAILED_APPLICATION_ACCESS",
      "displayName": "Failed application access",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "ADMIN",
      "category": "Compliance"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "0068",
      "title": "FUND_TRANSFER",
      "displayName": "Fund Transfer",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "ADMIN",
      "category": "Funds"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "0067",
      "title": "FUND_LOADING",
      "displayName": "Fund Loading",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "ADMIN",
      "category": "Funds"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "0066",
      "title": "FUND_LOADING_TRANSFER",
      "displayName": "Fund Loading and transfer",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "ADMIN",
      "category": "Funds"
    }
];
```

To put each list item under specific category I've loop through JSON and filtered it with ng-if directive to show specific list items if has same category.

**Here View (HTML Code)**

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="" ng-model="IsAllChecked" ng-change="CheckUncheckAll()"> 
    <span class="ml-1">Application Monitoring</span>
</label>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li ng-repeat="pr in privilegesList track by $index" ng-if="pr.category === 'Application Monitoring'">
        <label class="control-label">
            <input id="pr.title" type="checkbox" ng-model="pr.isActive" ng-change="CheckUncheckHeader()">
            <span>{{pr.displayName}}</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="" ng-model="IsAllChecked" ng-change="CheckUncheckAll()"> 
    <span class="ml-1">Client Management</span>
</label>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li ng-repeat="pr in privilegesList track by $index" ng-if="pr.category === 'Client Management'">
        <label class="control-label">
            <input id="pr.title" type="checkbox" ng-model="pr.isActive" ng-change="CheckUncheckHeader()">
            <span>{{pr.displayName}}</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="" ng-model="IsAllChecked" ng-change="CheckUncheckAll()"> 
    <span class="ml-1">Compliance</span>
</label>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li ng-repeat="pr in privilegesList track by $index" ng-if="pr.category === 'Compliance'">
        <label class="control-label">
            <input id="pr.title" type="checkbox" ng-model="pr.isActive" ng-change="CheckUncheckHeader()">
            <span>{{pr.displayName}}</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="" ng-model="IsAllChecked" ng-change="CheckUncheckAll()"> 
    <span class="ml-1">Funds</span>
</label>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li ng-repeat="pr in privilegesList track by $index" ng-if="pr.category === 'Funds'">
        <label class="control-label">
            <input id="pr.title" type="checkbox" ng-model="pr.isActive" ng-change="CheckUncheckHeader()">
            <span>{{pr.displayName}}</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Doing it ng-if seems to work fine but i want to do it with something more better solution (if there is any). Also i want to add Check/Uncheck feature to all categories and their respective child items. So if i check any category all child checkboxes will also be checked. And if any/all item checkbox gets unchecked that parent checkbox should be unchecked.

I've following JS code which seems to serves the check/uncheck all. I'm able to do this for specific category but i want to have script that do it for all categories and its sub checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this script be useful.

```js
angular.module('someApp', [])
  .controller('someController', function someController($scope) {
    $scope.getCategories = getCategories;
    $scope.getPrivilegesByCategory = getPrivilegesByCategory;
    $scope.selectCategory = selectCategory;
    $scope.checkCategory = checkCategory;
    $scope.privileges = getCategories().reduce(
      function(acc, category, index) {
        acc.push({
          category: category,
          data: getPrivilegesByCategory(category)
        });
        return acc;
      }, []);
  });

angular.bootstrap(
  document.body, ['someApp']
);

function getCategories() {
  var categories = privilegesService().reduce(
    function(acc, privilege) {
      if (acc.indexOf(privilege.category) === -1) {
        acc.push(privilege.category);
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);
  return categories;
}

function getPrivilegesByCategory(category) {
  var privileges = privilegesService().filter(
    function(privilege) {
      return privilege.category === category;
    });
  return privileges;
}

function selectCategory(item) {
  checkCategory(item);
  item.data.forEach(function(privilege) {
    privilege.isActive = !item.isActive;
  });
}

function checkCategory(item) {
  var res = item.data.filter(function(privilege) {
    return privilege.isActive !== true;
  });
  item.isActive = res.length === 0;
}

function privilegesService() {
  return [{
      "uuid": "0023",
      "title": "AM_FULL_ACCESS",
      "displayName": "Application monitoring Full access",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "ADMIN",
      "category": "Application Monitoring"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "0025",
      "title": "CM_FULL_ACCESS",
      "displayName": "Client management Full access",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "ADMIN",
      "category": "Client Management"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "0031",
      "title": "COMPLIANCE_FULL_ACCESS",
      "displayName": "Compliance Full access",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "ADMIN",
      "category": "Compliance"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "0054",
      "title": "FAILED_APPLICATION_ACCESS",
      "displayName": "Failed application access",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "ADMIN",
      "category": "Compliance"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "0068",
      "title": "FUND_TRANSFER",
      "displayName": "Fund Transfer",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "ADMIN",
      "category": "Funds"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "0067",
      "title": "FUND_LOADING",
      "displayName": "Fund Loading",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "ADMIN",
      "category": "Funds"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "0066",
      "title": "FUND_LOADING_TRANSFER",
      "displayName": "Fund Loading and transfer",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "ADMIN",
      "category": "Funds"
    }
  ];
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="someController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in privileges">
    <label class="h5 mb-2">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectCategory(item)" ng-model="item.isActive"> 
        <span class="ml-1" ng-bind="item.category"></span>
    </label>
    <ul class="list-unstyled ml-4">
      <li ng-repeat="pr in item.data track by $index">
        <label class="control-label">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="pr.isActive" ng-change="checkCategory(item)">
                <span ng-bind="pr.displayName"></span>
            </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll implement this and share my experience.